# Excel behaves differently for the same file which is in local computer vs in Google Drive

Tags: excel, vba, google-drive-api, excel-2010

First, I create a new workbook, make one module and put a simple sub :

```
Sub test()
MsgBox ""
End Sub
```

There's nothing on all of the three sheets which exist by default when creating a new workbook in Excel.

I save it as "Book1.xlsm" in drive D: of my computer, then I quit Excel
I copy this "Book1.xlsm" to virtual drive K: of my Google Drive for Desktop app.

case-A
I open the "Book1.xlsm" which in drive D:, 
open the VBA editor window, 
then I close the "Book1.xlsm", 
but the "Book1.xlsm" is still seen in the VBA editor as in the image below :
[image]

I quit Excel app.

Case-B
Then open the "Book1.xlsm" which in virtual drive K: (Google Drive for Desktop), 
open the VBA editor window, 
then I close the "Book1.xlsm", 
the "Book1.xlsm" is not seen in the VBA editor as in the image below :
[image]

I quit the Excel app.

Then I do again case-A, but this time without quitting the Excel app - I do case-B.
The VBA editor show like this :
[image]

As seen in the image above, 
the first "Book1.xlsm" is the one that I opened from drive K:, 
the second "Book1.xlsm" is the one that I already close (which I opened from drive D:) but it's still seen in the VBA editor.

Then I close the "Book1.xlsm" (which I opened from drive K:), the VBA editor is seen just like in the image of Case-A, although in the Excel app show that no workbook is opened :
[image]

My question:
X. Is Google Drive for Desktop messing the Excel app ?
Y. Or is Google Drive for Desktop "correcting" the already messed Excel app ?
Z. How do I solve this problem in order that when I open the xlsm file from my local computer then close it, the VBA editor won't still show the file just like if I do in the case-B ?

FYI, I'm planning to put the same question to Google Drive for Desktop community.

Any kind of explanation would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced and I'm sorry if this is not the right place to put this kind of question.

One more thing,
if I quit Google Drive for Desktop app, then there is no case-A. In other words, Excel behaves correctly - not showing the "Book1.xlsm" in the VBA editor after the workbook is close. However, if I run Google Drive for Desktop again, then I experience case-A again.

Answer (score 1):

This is very strange and you are absolutely right! As soon as the "Google Drive" programm is quited, the VBE project list is updated and the "ghost" project(s) disappear!

```
Option Explicit

Sub List_VBAProjects_and_Workbooks()

    Dim VBPrj As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook

    If Workbooks.Count > 0 Then
    Debug.Print """book1.xlsm"" is opened and the makro is started"
    Debug.Print "------------------------------------------------"
    Else
    Debug.Print """book1.xlsm"" is closed but the project is still visible and callable in the VBE"
    Debug.Print "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    End If
    Debug.Print "Count of open workbooks : " & Workbooks.Count

    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "1st call"
    
    For Each VBPrj In Application.VBE.VBProjects
        Debug.Print "--- " & VBPrj.Name
    Next VBPrj

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        Debug.Print "--- " & wb.Name
    Next wb
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print

    On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks("book1.xlsm").Close
    On Error GoTo 0

    'This code is not executed when "book1.xlsm" was open and is closed
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "2nd call"
    For Each VBPrj In Application.VBE.VBProjects
        Debug.Print "--- " & VBPrj.Name
    Next VBPrj

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        Debug.Print "--- " & wb.Name
    Next wb
    
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print

End Sub
```

The output of the above code with the first run looks like:

```
"book1.xlsm" is opened and the makro is started
------------------------------------------------
Count of open workbooks : 1

1st call
--- VBAProject
--- book1.xlsm


"book1.xlsm" is closed but the project is still visible and callable in the VBE
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Count of open workbooks : 0

1st call
--- VBAProject

2nd call
--- VBAProject
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Btw, did you experience the same thing like me ?

Comment: I tried to understand your problem and was astonished to see several projects open in VBE. The according workbook files I had already closed the day before. So yes! I do experience the same (or at least very similar issues)!